# Node.js Execution order queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

At the end of my code, I have two actions that run at the same time, a query that makes an Atler table. The second insertion.

The problem is that sometimes the insertion happens before the alter table.

How can I execute the first part of the code in the for loop for all keys, then proceed with the insertion ?

```
if (count >1) {
       for( var i = 0; i < keys.length -1; i++ ) {
         client.execute (queryadd, { prepare: true }, function (err) {
         console.log("do");
         });
       }
    }


 client.execute(queryinsert, { prepare: true }, function (err) {
   console.log(err);
   client.shutdown();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs cassandra driver supports promises, so it can be done as simple as:

```
if (count > 1) {
   for (const key of keys) {
     await client.execute(queryadd);
   }
}

await client.execute(queryinsert, params, { prepare: true });
await client.shutdown();
```

If you want to execute all `queryadd` in parallel and then queryinsert, then you can do:

```
if (count > 1) {
   let queryadds = [];
   for (const key of keys) {
     queryadds.push(client.execute(queryadd));
   }
   await Promise.all(queryadds);
}

await client.execute(queryinsert, params, { prepare: true });
await client.shutdown();
```

Comment: if I use await, I get Unexpected identifier for client ... ?

Comment: Take a look at https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await or https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html

Comment: If you dont want to use es6/7 then just use this library https://caolan.github.io/async/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using callback-based execution, you should use a control flow library. For example using [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
const async = require('async');

async.eachSeries(keys, function eachKey(key, next) {
  // Changing schema
  client.execute(buildMyAlterQueryBasedOnKey(key), next);
}, function eachFinished(err) {
  if (err) {
    // TODO: Handle err
  }
  client.execute(queryinsert, params, { prepare: true }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // Finished, you should invoke your callback here
  });
});
```

If you are using Promises, you can chain the following call using [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Some recommendations:

- You should prepare DDL queries (ie: `ALTER TABLE`).
- `shutdown()` should be used [once in your application lifetime](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.2/faq/#should-i-shut-down-the-pool-after-executing-a-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your logic as if it was sequential, and run it via [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs):

Step 1. Put it into function

```
function logic(count, keys, queryadd, queryinsert, client) {
    if (count > 1)
       for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
         client.execute(queryadd, { prepare: true });

    client.execute(queryinsert, { prepare: true });
    client.shutdown();
}
```

Step 2. Run that function via nsynjs:

```
nsynjs.run(logic,{},count, keys, queryadd, queryinsert, client, function () {
    console.log('Done');
});
```

Nsynjs will automatically detect if any function returns a promise, and waits until promise resolved/rejected before evaluating next expression.